# Lock for Dictionary.Count

Tags: c#, locking

Is there any benefit, or harm, in locking when accessing simple properties of a collection, specifically `.Count`?  (is this advisable, inadvisable, or doesn't matter in the slightest?)  (Of course I need to lock it on any writes or reads)

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> database = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
private object databaseLock = new object();
public int Count
{
    get
    {
        lock (databaseLock)
        {
            return database.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Personally I'm thinking it might be advisable, simply to hammer down the convention that access to the dictionary needs to be locked, not for any actual reasons[*].  Also the possibility that more operations than one might expect in whatever property you're accessing.

[*] Knowing that in (most) collections in C# the `Count` is an integer that is maintained by it so should always be an atomic operation

Comment: Well, if it is not needed, you are just adding noise and making your code harder to read and understand. Not a good thing.

Comment: Very true, although playing devil's advocate I would respond that if someone can't understand a `lock` statement as easily as a `get` statement, a class using this pattern overall would be near unreadable to them

Answer (score 5):

Yes, locking is needed in case of concurrent writes because the docs for `Dictionary` do not guarantee that this would be safe. You cannot assume anything about its internals.

Exceptions to this rule would require extreme circumstances.

TL;DR: Rely only on documented behavior or you'll find yourself in a world of hurt eventually.

Comment: I don't believe "concurrent writes" applies to the hypothetical question I'm posing, but mentioning that the docs for `Dictionary` do not guarantee anything about the operation of it's `Count` and therefore it may be needed does

Comment: With "concurrent writes" I mean "one read of count happening concurrently with at least one write operation". Maybe I did not bring that across too well.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of code heavily belongs in the "harm" category.  Very serious kind of harm as well.  The lock just doesn't protect **anything**.  There's nothing that stops a thread from adding or removing an item from/to the dictionary a nanosecond after the property getter exited the lock.  Which makes the Count value you return nothing but garbage.  You have no idea how many items are actually in the dictionary when you get the value.  By far the most harmful aspect of this bug is that it is *usually* correct.

This code will *guarantee* that you created a threading race, by far the worst kind of bug to diagnose.

Comment: I disagree that _this code_ would guarantee a threading race, how threads use this code is the only thing that can do that (i.e. if they require the Count value to be accurate that code should get its own lock before calling it, which will simply make this lock redundant)

Comment: Well, good, it does sound like you know how to do it properly.  Then you also know that this lock is just wasted space.  So don't use it.

Comment: Very good point, but I disagree that this code is guaranteed to be harmful. Without knowing the exact use case, it's hard to judge whether this is wrong or not. How about the use case, such as periodically polling the count for statistical purposes?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As usr points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13771278/18573) `Dictonary.Count` is not thread-safe. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) says:

> enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write
>   accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration.

Which means synchronization *is* required. Note that the same lock needs to be used by any other code that may be modifying the collection. This is highly error prone, if the Dictionary is used by multiple threads consider using  [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead

Comment: Your first paragraph relies on information inferred from guessing or reflector, neither of which is stable knowledge over time.

Comment: It was guessing, I corrected after reading documentation on your advice :)

Comment: If you have an answer that's wrong you should either just delete it, or edit it to remove all incorrect information.  It's highly confusing and potentially misleading to state a whole bunch of things only to say at the bottom "oh, yeah, all of that was wrong".